# Twitter widget appears to be broken: "Application not installed"

Tags: samsung, stock-android, twitter

I'm having trouble with the Twitter app on my Samsung Galaxy S4. The widget was misbehaving, so I thought I would remove it from my homescreen and put it back. What has happened instead is that the widget refuses to come back. Whenever I try to place it, it will simply say "Application not installed."

I've tried the following:

- Reboot my phone
- Reinstall the Twitter app
- Clear the app's cache and data
- Remove the MicroSD card, reinstall, and attempt to use the widget
- Several combinations of the above.

Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong here? I realize this is probably a silly question

Comment: I just did a hard reset of my phone. Still the same result. I'm thinking at this point that it is a bug with Twitter's app.

Comment: Twitter's latest update is causing some issues for people, afaik a fix is in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with another app (not Twitter) I went into my app manager and saw that the app was installed on my "External Storage" even if I never moved it there. I moved it back to the Internal Storage and it was fixed. My card was already fine to begin with but for some reason, the widget didn't like it. 
Anyway, I never recommend putting apps on the SD card, it slowed my S3 to a crawl. Keep it for media and docs.